# jquery click an img hide an LI

Tags: jquery

i have something similar to the following... used a python script to JSON to populate.

```
<ul>
<li id="p1" class="x">val1 <img id="ip1" class="redx" src="redx.gif"/></li>
<li id="p2" class="x">val2 <img id="ip2" class="redx" src="redx.gif"/></li>
<li id="p3" class="x">val3 <img id="ip3" class="redx" src="redx.gif"/></li>
<li id="p4" class="x">val4 <img id="ip4" class="redx" src="redx.gif"/></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like some jquery to... when click the red x image.. to hide the whole LI cell it is in.

I have tried a few things but ... to no avail.

EDIT: **All in all**.. this doesnt seem to trigger    ... this seems like a fundamental issue.

```
$(function(){
    function removeli() {
      alert("got here" + this.id);
    }
    $("redx").click(removeli);
});
```

Any ideas on the final jquery code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

need a `.` prefix for classes

```
$('.redx').live('click', removeli);
```

---

updated code using live:

```
$(function() {
    $('.redx').live('click', function() {
        $(this).parent('li').hide(); // or .remove()
    });
});
```

using delegate (will only work if the `<ul>` doesn't change, only the `<li>`'s within it do):

```
$(function() {
    $('ul').delegate('img', 'click', function() {
        $(this).parent('li').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: LOL  even that being true. still no go after fixing the syntax.  In firebug should i be seeing an onclick added to all of the li's in the code?

Comment: that is most likely because you are adding the rows dynamically after setting up the click handler. use either `live` or `delegate` to add the event handlers as @Tatu suggested. that will work for newly inserted elements as well.

Comment: i finally figured out what was wrong w/ TATU's syntax.  Thank you for updated.  Thank you all for helping! :)  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".redx").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: the onclick doesnt seem to be firing.